# Send FormData and String Data Together Through JQuery AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the below that uploads an image using JQuery's AJAX function

```
var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;
var img_data = new FormData($("form")[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: 'add.php',
    data: img_data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

I'd like to include a string with the FormData sent.  I tried the following, but no luck

```
data: img_data {id: id},
```

What's the correct syntax here?

Comment: store the id in a hidden input in the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#append%28%29)

```
var img_data = new FormData($("form")[0]);
img_data.append('id', id);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a JSON data object and pass that as application/json and process the data within add.php:

```
var data = {
    id : <?php echo !empty($id) ? $id : "''",
    img_data : new FormData($("form")[0])
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'add.php',
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Although unconventional, you could also append the data as a query string to the URL with the POST. You'd also need to edit add.php to get this parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'add.php?id=' + id,
    data: img_data,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```